# set NSArray protocol in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsarray, protocols

In Objective-C you can do something like `NSArray<ReviewC>* reviews;` in order to make a variable NSArray which follows the protocol ReviewC, I need to do the same in Swift, I need to make NSArray follow a protocol, it has to be An NSArray, not an Array.

I know I can do that on Objective C, and that I can mix Objective C with Swift, but I prefer to use Swift if possible.

Comment: why would something be `NSArray` and also conform to protocol `ReviewC`? Is this a custom subclass or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it this way:

```
protocol ReviewC {
    // protocol definition goes here
}


var reviews : NSArray = NSArray() as? protocol<ReviewC> as! NSArray
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable that conforms to a protocol, then assign the NSArray to it, just make sure NSArray conforms to that protocol.

```
var object: MyProtocol = NSArray(array: someArray)
```

in your case:

```
var object: ReviewC = NSArray(array: someArray)
```